# External Authentication failure ASP Identity OWIN Middleware

Tags: authentication, asp.net-identity, owin

I use Google and Facebook authentication through ASP Identity framework in my site, the external login for both providers works fine at certain times but at times it doesn't, I couldn't understand where the issue is from but it works fine when I restart App.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2.d__1d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at SweetNightsIn.Identity.SiteUserManager.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at SweetNightsIn.Web.Controllers.AccountController.d__3.MoveNext()

OWIN startup.cs looks like this,

```
// For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(IdentityDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString(AppConstants.LoginPath)

        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        FacebookAuthenticationOptions facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"],
            AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"],
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email",
            BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler()
        };

        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAppId"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAppSecret"],
            Caption = "Google +"
        });
```

Please revert if you need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular error was due to Facebook API changes, the major change that involved the response from API being upgraded to JSON format